# wifi disconnects and then repeatedly asks for password

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.  The wifi will randomly disconnect and repeatedly ask for the password.  However clicking show password reveals the correct password.

I have tried turning the wifi off and back on under Settings.

I have tried restarting network-manager with `service network-manager restart`

I have tried deleting what is in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ and again turning wifi off and on and restarting network-manager.

I've even tried `nmcli n off` and `nmcli n on`, yet it continues to constantly ask for the password (with the correct password already in the dialog box) and never connects.

The only way to get it to reconnect is to reboot.

Is there some way to get it to reconnect without rebooting (or ideally keep it from disconnecting in the first place)?